# How to send integer value of textbox to [WebMethod] using ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, webmethod

```
[code page="c#"]
[WebMethod]
public static int bubblesort(int[] arr)
{       
   //some code here

    return arr;
}
```

```js
var text;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").on("click", function() {
        text = $("#text1").val();
        option = $('#dropdownfilter').val();

            bsortedarr(text);
        
    });
});

function bsortedarr(text) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "default.aspx/bubblesort",
        data: JSON.stringify({ arr: text }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
          //code
        },
        error: function(response) {
           //code
        }
    });
}
```

I created WebMethod which return sorted list of array using bubblesort. When I select option bsort and give integer as input such as 100,10,1 into textbox. So I am passing that textbox value into ajax call by using `stringify({ arr: text})`. I want to pass this text value which is "100,10,1" into WebMethod but it is not happening. So I am trying to split this with ',' and want to return array format list but it is in integer type so not able to return.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]),` You need to post an array since you are accepting a `List<>` and `JSON.stringify()` might not be required here

Comment: am passing that textbox value into ajax call by using stringify({ arr: text}) I want to pass this text value which is "100,10,1" into webmethod but it is not happening.so I am trying to split this ',' and want to return array format string.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(text.split(',')),`

Comment: thanks @Satpal but in webmthod I change type as string and I am not able to return

Comment: I am getting error when returning array because I am using type as int and passing array as int.so how can I return array in string format any idea

Comment: I splited textbox value and converted into ineger  and piushed into new variable array on jquery side now I am not getting on webmethod side how can i get sorted array in string format here

Comment: stringify itself suggests that it will send anything as string. You can parse it on webmethod once you get it

Answer (score 0):

You should first define the `atxt` variable. It will hold the value of the textbox, the code will be something like this:

`var atxt = $('TEXTBOX_SELECTOR').val();`

After that use this variable to pass value through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

**Version 1**
Changes in your WebMethod:

- If you want to return an array, change the return type to `object`
- Split your `text` then convert your array to a List of int
- If you want to sort the List, simply use `Sort()` instead of a loop

WebMethod updated:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object bubblesort(string arr)
{
    // Split then convert to List<int>
    var sra = arr.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
    // Sort the List
    sra.Sort();

    return sra;
}
```

---

**Version 2**
If you changed your WebMethod parameter type to `int[]`, simply sort the array:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object bubblesort(int[] arr)
{
    // ----------------------------------------
    // --- Return a Lit of int
    // ----------------------------------------
    // var sra = arr.ToList();
    // sra.Sort();
    // return sra;      

    // ----------------------------------------
    // --- Return a List of string
    // ----------------------------------------
    // return sra.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();

    // ----------------------------------------
    // --- Return a string containing all numbers sorted
    var sra = arr.ToList();
    sra.Sort();
    return String.Join("", sra.Select(i => i.ToString()));
}
```

Test if input is a list of numbers separated by a comma:

```
text = $("#text1").val();
var pattern = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/);
var isNumbers = pattern.test(text.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
```

And split your `text`:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ arr: text.split(',') })
```

Comment: but using split into webmethod giving error that system.array does not contain a definition for split split

Comment: Is it because you changed your WebMethod parameter type to int[]? If it's a string type and your ajax data is still `JSON.stringify({arr: text})`, it's working.

Comment: Use `return sra.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();` if you want to return a List of string instead of a list of int.

Comment: I am getting sorted array in result but want in such format as [1,4,67,666].want to show alert in that format but I am getting in  1267666 in such format .So should I use string concatenation on [webmethod] side to get result in such format

Comment: Please see my update: `return String.Join("", sra.Select(i => i.ToString()));`

Comment: how can I do the validation that user giving input into textbox must be an integer value not a string  and integers should be comma seperated if not then it should give alert that it should be integer

Comment: how can I do the validation that user giving input into textbox must be an integer value not a string and if not then it should give alert that it should be integer and also integers should be comma seperated . @krlzlx

Comment: Please see my update: a regex to check if input is a list of integers separated by comma (and removes any white spaces from the input). It will be my last update. Please accept the answer and if you have a new question, create another one.

Comment: You're welcome. Are you going to validate the answer @ziel?